# Make this site Wii-browseable

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, browser-support

Wikipedia, when browsed via the Wii's [Internet Channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Channel), has a nice large font view. I'd like to be able to browse Gaming.SE from a Wii in a similar fashion, too. Currently I can't even search questions or tags since the Wii uses a virtual keyboard on input fields such that search on type won't work and there is no <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key...

Comment: A few weeks or months down the road after we go live and get a real name, I bet a whole lot of new users are going to be confused when they see all these references to some "Gaming.SE" on our Meta site.

Comment: I think this is a very good idea, but only when it is applied to the whole SE network, and in a generic fashion so the PSP, and iOS and Adroid devices are included too. (BTW: confirmed the wii specific problem.)

Comment: @Grace Note♦: I guess we could find/replace all gaming.SE references then, by hand if necessary. But point taken

Comment: Ahaha, sorry, I wasn't actually trying to tell you to change it. I was just musing to myself about this.

Comment: @Grace Note♦: no, but in fact you're right, it will read strange if someone tries to catch up with meta's history in a year or two. Although, someone browsing meta should quite soon figure out about SE...

Comment: @GraceNote Be sure to delete these comments if you update it or they will be even more confused- HOLY COW YOU WROTE THIS IN 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

The Wii (and it's browser) are well abandoned by now, but even if it were still supported by Nintendo, Stack Exchange is another matter:

> #### Which browsers are supported?
>
> **We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use.** This does not include beta, developer, nightly, canary, or any other pre-release versions of browsers, which are not supported.
> <sub>- [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)</sub>

Please also see Stack Exchange's [visualisation of supported browsers](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/).

---

Note for read-only access, you might have some luck with services like [FrogFind](http://frogfind.com/), which is a search engine built for vintage PCs and browsers, however in my testing it only worked for certain pages (and even then, didn't provide all the content on the page).

Answer (score 6):

If read-only access is enough for you -- have you tried [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com/questions.php?site=gaming.stackexchange)?

[Example](http://stackmobile.com/view_question.php?site=meta.gaming.stackexchange&id=1033)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Asking questions via virtual keyboard (I have a notebook, no USB keyboard) would be a pain in the ass anyway...

Answer (score 5):

A Solution for the Wii specific problem would be to add a submit button on the search form, which is also doubles as a link to the search page when the form is empty.

Comment: repeatedly declined on meta.so

Comment: [Make the search box handheld-device friendly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/make-the-search-box-handheld-device-friendly) is what Jeff meant for example. Although I wish he'd revise this in these new times... @Jeff why not hire someone specifically for usability and accessibility issues?

Comment: @tobias nope, we will never have a button there as long as I am alive to prevent it from happening. Works fine on correctly written browsers, such as Android, iPhone, even Opera Mobile (latest)..

Comment: @Jeff: I guess the sites display different on these devices than on a PC? Could you then at least have SE let render the mobile version when a Wii is detected?

Comment: +1 even though I know know much about this type of thing.