# Prioritising our bugs and requests for CM review

Tags: discussion, community, stack-exchange

Last week, a proposal was announced on Meta Stack Exchange to address the growing workload of the CM team, and for them to actually start addressing community requests and feedback again: [Our Commitment to Responding to Meta and Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344586/179041).

Long story short, if something requires review by a CM, we should tag it [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) and they will get to it when they can. This new system is set to start soon, following a short trial period beginning March 16.

I thought it might be a good idea for us to review some of our old [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) and [feature-requests](/questions/tagged/feature-requests), to see if there's any that we should bring to SE's attention. Note this is **not** a guarantee that these bugs or requests will be approved, or handled in the way we want (in fact I'm pretty sure some below will be flatly denied) - but bringing them forward for CM input will at least provide a way to get some closure.

## What we need from you

Pick one of the following posts (or perhaps even a different one we missed) and post it as an answer with your reasons for wanting it addressed. **One question per post** please, votes on these answers will be used to decide what our priorities are. (Of course if the one you want addressed is already posted, upvote it instead). At the end of this process, we will pick the top 5 and add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to them:

---

### Feature Requests

- Add the photo widget for Screenshot of the Week: [Do we want to enable the photo widget for our site?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14925/)
- Better support for tables in markdown: [Can better support be added for creating tables, for science?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4467/)

  - Same again: [Is There a Way to Post Spreadsheets in an Answer?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11320/28182)
  - And better support for equations too? [Math Equations, let's use the math.stackexchange version](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5384)
- Controller buttons for markdown too: [Console controller button images instead of <kbd> used mainly for PC keys](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8480/)

  - Again: [Markdown or HTML for gamepad buttons](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14717/)
- Review Queues should respect ignored tags: [Can the review queues respect ignored tags?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7079/)
- Define and show a template for tag wiki format editing: [Could we have the preferred tag wiki format indicated to suggesting users?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8371/)
- Arqade Meta should say 'meta' in the header: [Put the Meta back in Meta Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9830/)
- Gaming-esque links in profile (Steam, Twitch, Youtube etc) instead of Github: [Can we replace the GitHub Profile field with Steam ID?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10440/)

  - The profile website link could be smarter too: [Can the profile 'website link' be made to render Steam/YouTube/Twitch channel names like the Twitter one does?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10787/)
- Ability to mark certain tags as 'shouldn't appear in page title': [Allow tags to be blacklisted specifically from appearing in the HTML page title](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2266/)

  - The same for Twitter too: [Setting priority for Twitter #hashtags from question tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2781/)
- Allow Duplicate titles so long as tags are different: [Disable the "question with the same title" filter on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5687/)
- 'Related Questions' should prioritise 'all tag' matches: [Make 'Related' links prioritize questions matching *all* tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/)
- 'View a random question' button: [Random Question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8677/)
- Old chat theme: [Can We Use the Old Chat Theme?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4865/)
- Onebox twitch links in chat: [Onebox Twitch.tv links (both streams and archives) in chat](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7604/)
- Add a way to request 'Peer Review' of edits: [Is there some way to request peer review on an edit?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13462/28182)

### Bugs

- Flags are handled incorrectly when answer is converted to comment: [flag without review](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7102/)
- Visited Hyperlink colour is too dull and hard to see: [Visited hyperlinks are hard to distinguish against plain text](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11779/)

  - And [Visited-links are too low-contrast](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5308/)
  - And [Visited links are invisible on new profile](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10439/)
  - And [Should hyperlinks be more notorious?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12055/)
- Mod PMs have some funky rendering issues: [Moderator message pages aren't limited in width](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7307/)
- The flag modal covers the answer being flagged: [The form for flagging an answer obscures the answer being flagged](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2465/)
- Bugs RE: browsing on different devices:

  - 3DS: [Cannot search Arqade mobile site from Nintendo 3DS](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5009/)
  - Wii: [Make this site Wii-browseable](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1033/)

### Migration Path Requests

- Game Dev: [Add "Game Development" to off-topic selection list when flagging a post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1754/)
- Software Recs: [Should we have a migration path to softwarerecs for game recommendation questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11033/)

Comment: How large is the pool of 'users' having site modification privileges, anyway? Is it only direct employees of Stack Exchange, Inc.? Can't we have a dedicated back-end developer, for example, or one shared with a few sister-pages? Some of these bugs and requests are more than five years old, and never have seem to garnered any attention.

Comment: @Joachim I don't have exact numbers but my understanding is that both the CM and Dev teams are fairly small, and are swamped as far as I am aware. This exercise in itself is an attempt to prioritise, organise and reduce their workload as much as possible.

Comment: I addressed the [meta header issue](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9830/) there. I think the changing of the graphics will be easy and swift.

Comment: Is the sprite sheet mentioned in [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8480/console-controller-button-images-instead-of-kbd-used-mainly-for-pc-keys) still available, or has it been replaced by multiple other ones, or different methods?

Comment: @Joachim I imagine the sprite sheet referenced in that question is long gone - but that doesn't mean there isn't a newer one in use for the site. Although, given the SE theming rollout it's likely the site doesn't use a site-specific sprite sheet any more.

Answer (score 11):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as of 7th Dec, 2020. Announced on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/179041).

---

### [Markdown support for tables](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4467/)

I'd personally like to see a neater way of handling tables. Our current workaround is to use `<pre>` tags* to render the table in the preformatted format ([example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/331103/28182)).

Some sites have access to the MathJax extension, and can use it's table formatting. [Here's an example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133767/16451) from RPG.SE:

[image: Table in RPG SE]

But, MathJax markdown is clunky - and enabling the entire library for tables (and maybe the occasional equation) would be overkill for our use case. MathJax is primarily built to be a formatting library for scientific/math purposes, that just so happens to support rendering tables because that's a common use case in the math world.

So if SE is going to do this, they should do it right. Rather than enabling MathJax here, SE should **add markdown support for tables** in the manner described by the [Markdown Extended Syntax](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/):

> [image: Markdown extended syntax example]

---

<sub>* This is visually the same as code blocks, but code blocks insert both `<pre>` and `<code>` HTML tags, so they are semantically different.</sub>

Comment: We could probably use MathJax, if we're being perfectly honest. It's not exactly rare to find a question or an answer discussing a game's formulae.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I mean, we could, but our use case for MathJax is a lot less than other sites. A lot of formulas that are linked here are either simple enough that code formatting solves the case, or if they are complex (like, the Pokeball catch/shake mechanics), a screenshot usually suffices for our needs. It's not often we need to write, tweak and maintain large formulas.

Comment: Screenshots are not exactly accessible to everyone, so I'm all for improving that where we can.

Comment: @Wrigglenite True. Perhaps we could use MathJax then - but I'd still prefer a nicer way of doing tables than using MathJax as it is quite a heavy plugin. Perhaps consider writing an answer for [this request](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5384)?

Answer (score 9):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - The Photo widget is now live on Arqade

---

## [Photo widget](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14925/)

From the thread: [Do we want to enable the photo widget for our site?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14925/)

#### Advantages (partially and shamelessly taken from that thread):

- It adds visual interest to the main page.
- It adds a sense of community to the website as well as the network.
- It will add an increase participation in the website's possibilities.
- It will lead more users to the Meta counterpart of Arqade.
- It shouldn't bother users that aren't interested.
- It opens up a slot in the '*Featured on Meta*' widget.
- I reckon it's not hard to implement, since it's a dedicated `<div>` with `class="s-sidebarwidget mb16 photo-of-the-week"`, presumably with dynamic content based on upvotes of threads with a specific title - my point being that it won't be hard to maintain.

Here's a mockup, made by copying the `<div>` from [Photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) to Arqade, and using the last '*Screenshot of the Week*' winner (showing, by the way, that [the aspect ratio is neatly maintained](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14928/222022)):

[image: Photo widget mockup]

And, to address [Booga Roo's concern](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14929/222022): it seems the widget supports APNG files (I copied an APNG link from Imgur to the widget, and it works perfectly fine. GIF doesn't, though..).

#### Disadvantages:

- It does not (yet) seem to support (animated) GIFs.
- It might get boring to see the same screenshot week after week. <sup>[3](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14931/222022)</sup> This means a script of rotation might have to be implemented, and linked to other threads (shuffling, for example, through the current contest, and showing the winner(s) of the last thread(s)).
- The only other sounds of protest had nothing to do with the widget itself, but with the longevity of the '*Screenshot of the Week*' feature, which I think should be a concern for later, and, all the same, I'm sure we will find ways to make interesting use of the widget.

Comment: I realize this shouldn't be a priority, since there are years-old bugs that really need attention, but it was the first on the list, and I felt like giving it a go to get the posting started :)

Comment: The same screenshot for weeks? What? If it's a weekly screenshot contest, how will that happen?

Comment: @Corsaka Currently the contest accepts entries for a week, then it accepts voting for another week to give all entries a fair chance. So, a winning entry may be up for a couple of weeks if only winners of the previous "week" are featured.

Comment: @Corsaka What Booga Roo said ↑

Answer (score 7):

> **Update**: This has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by a CM - likely following the (re)addition of underlines to link text

---

### [Visited hyperlinks are hard to distinguish against plain text](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11779/)

Accessibility bugs are important, plus this one is (as far as I am aware) site specific unlike some of the others.

Answer (score 5):

> **Update**: This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

---

### [Arqade Meta should say 'Meta' in the header](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9830/28182)

Community member Joachim has stepped up and done an excellent job with [the design](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14988/28182) already, so this should be an easy one to knock off.